# Marquee on every item of listview

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `listview` of `textview`. I want to set marque on every `textview`? After struggling for hours I haven't been successful in doing so. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `marquee` behavior only works when the view is selected. A trick that you can use is to make each TextView selected from your Adapter :

```
textView.setSelected(true);
```

Comment: you should also use singleLine="true" instead of lines="1"